# Impossible to hide a DIV in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some trouble to hide some div in my application, this code is used in jQuery UI tabs.

In the controller :

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View("MyView", model);
}
```

In the view "MyView", I have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divToHide1').hide();
    $('#divToHide2').hide();
});
</script>


<div id="divToHide1">
</div>   

<div id="divToHide2">
</div>
```

The problem the div are never hidded, any idea ?

Thanks,

Update1 :
when I switch to second tab, I do the prcedure below. The switch to thez tab is ok, I receive an "alert1", and I receive "1" correspondinf to the length, but the div is still visible.

```
 function e2() {
    var jqxhr = $.post("/Controller/MyAction", function (data) {
        $('#tabs-2').html(data);
    })
    .success(function () {
        alert('alert1');
    })
    .error(function () { })
    .complete(function () {
        alert($('#divToHide1').length);
        $('#divToHide1').hide();    
    });
}
```

Update2 : I tried with class instead of id ... and look ok

Comment: Just to confirm - you're including jQuery into your HTML above the `document.ready`, yeah?

Comment: Are you getting any errors appearing in the console?

Comment: The divs you're trying to hide - are they appended to the document though jQuery after document load?

Comment: @Rory yes, when I click on the tab > controller > return a view and the div to hidden are on this view. I tried to place jquery here and other places no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $(". and not $("# as selector, it's strange but that's work

Answer (score 1):

Do this in CSS:

```
.ui-tabs-hide {

     display: none;
}
```

If you're using jQuery UI Tabs, it will append classes to your elements. All your inactive views will have css class "ui-tabs-hide".

Answer (score 0):

What you have written there should work. Have you tried .toggle or binding the action to a link/button opposed to on document load, see if that helps. You do have Jquery included?

Comment: I have x tabs (jQuery UI tab). When I switch tab some part are not visible on the tabs and are display depending of a dropdown value